# Set cpu usage full inside docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm using docker-compose version 2.4
And also with docker-compose, I'm using buildbot

Build time taken so long, I'd like to use docker cpu usage as much as possible
when do docker stats, it uses cpu from 0% to 200%

so, I set docker-compose(ver.2.4) like below

```
services:
  worker:
    build:
      context: "./worker"
      dockerfile: "Dockerfile"
    cpu_count: 32
    cpu_percent: 100
    cpus: 32
```

when I do 'top' upon server, docker-worker process only use 1.7% of cpu.

How could i assign 32 cpus to docker-compose (worker)?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assigning [resources](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#resources) does not mean that it will start to use all or maximum resources you specified in `docker-compose` file.

when you run `top` it returns the actual usage of your docker container. which is `1.7%` and it can scale upto `32` or whatever value you specified in the Docker config for any resource.

The status that you expect that Docker should use its maximum resources what will happen in this case? see the example of memory when it consumes all the allocated memory.

**Out Of Memory Exceptions (OOME)**

> If your services or containers attempt to use more memory than the
>   system has available, you may experience an Out Of Memory Exception
>   (OOME) and a container, or the Docker daemon, might be killed by the
>   kernel OOM killer. To prevent this from happening, ensure that your
>   application runs on hosts with adequate memory and see Understand the
>   risks of running out of memory.

Comment: Sorry for miscommunication, When do docker stats, it uses 96.96% sometime uses appromaxiately 200%. But, checking build server 'top', it only uses 1.7%. To make build speed up, i hope docker container uses much resource of server. (Server i run docker-compose has 32 cores)

Comment: First thing if you are not aware of the resources that can container consume better to not limit the resources. Run docker inspect yourcontainer and check how much resources are allocated then will on way to compare top and docker stats

Comment: When I do docker inspect , there is no information about limitation cpu or memory. Is it different in docker-compose.yml case?

Comment: `for container in `docker ps -q`; do docker inspect $container | grep 'CpuCount\|Name' ; done` this will print all container allocated cpucount

Comment: you should see ```            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
```

Comment: hmm, it shows all zero like below.            "CpuShares": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198924/discussion-between-adiii-and-n-hwang).